# Error while trying integration between JMeter and Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, kibana, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I am trying to connect Jmeter to Kibana using this manual:
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/04/06/load-testing-with-jmeter-test-results-visualization-using-kibana-dashboards/comment-page-1/#comment-398399

- I am using JMeter 3.2, and downloaded elasticsearch-5.6.4.zip.
- I extract the zip and put the folder elasticsearch-5.6.4 in C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\lib
- I downloaded the jar JMeter_ElasticsearchListener.jar and put it in C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\lib\ext
- I restart JMeter and pressed add -> listener -> backend listener and get these errors:

`017-11-11 09:39:12,429 ERROR o.a.j.g.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui for org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder$HttpClientConfigCallback
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.actionPerformed(BackendListenerGui.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.clearGui(BackendListenerGui.java:281) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.createTestElement(GuiPackage.java:348) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AddToTree.doAction(AddToTree.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:74) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:59) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder$HttpClientConfigCallback
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        ... 25 more
    2017-11-11 09:39:40,782 ERROR o.a.j.g.a.AddToTree: Exception while adding a component to tree.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder$HttpClientConfigCallback
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.createTestElement(GuiPackage.java:359) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.AddToTree.doAction(AddToTree.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:74) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:59) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder$HttpClientConfigCallback
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.actionPerformed(BackendListenerGui.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.clearGui(BackendListenerGui.java:281) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.createTestElement(GuiPackage.java:348) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder$HttpClientConfigCallback
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.actionPerformed(BackendListenerGui.java:166) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
        at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListenerGui.clearGui(BackendListenerGui.java:281) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.createTestElement(GuiPackage.java:348) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        ... 17 more`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a jar, which is the REST client jar, just add the following jar to your lib folder (C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\lib)

```
elasticsearch-rest-client-5.6.4.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think JMeter recursively searches any folders in its "lib" folder looking for any .jars it can add to its classpath, so I would recommend either moving all .jars from the `elasticsearch-5.6.4` folder to JMeter's "lib" folder.

Alternatively you can add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
user.classpath=C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.2\lib\elasticsearch-5.6.4`
```

In both cases JMeter restart will be required to pick the libraries up.

More information:

- [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)